# Plotting and selecting specific data to plot

Tags: matlab

I need to plot concentration from two instruments so I can compare the results. Ineed to plot concentration from instrument (A) on one axis and concentration from another instrument (B) on the other. The problem is instrument A has a time of 1 hour where as instrument B has 1 minute.
How would I select a specific time where the instrument A can be plotted.

```
figure
plot(averagetime,averageconcentration_A),'color','r');
hold on
plot(num,(B_concentration_in_mgperlitre);
datetick('x')
ylabel 'Average Concentration(mg/litre)';
xlabel 'Average Time';
```

This plots a line plot against time.

Answer (score 0):

Perform linear interpolation to get data points for instrument A as if it also had a time of 1 minute.

see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation

Answer (score 0):

Perform interpolation on your data with bigger interval. There are interpolation functions in Malab. However, you need to be careful about the method. If your data moves linearly then you will be able to get a good result as your time stamped are consistent. 
I think by looking at your data you would judge the linear propagation of the points. If you are not sure about the function that fits to your data use [curve-fitting](http://au.mathworks.com/products/curvefitting/) toolbox to find the best match. Then you need to interpolate according to that function within two points. Curvefitting can be applied reginoally. I mean you don't need to fit a curve for the whole data, finding the best match between t consecutive points will suit your purpose. 
In case you want to use linear interpolation, use Matlab function [interp1](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html)
And this lib [lininterp1f](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8627-fast-linear-interpolation)